# Transform array of objects to another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

i am currently struggling to transform an array of objects to fit my needs.

My initial array is looking like this:

```
 [{
    "adId": "uuid"
    "carBrand": "audi",
    "carColor: "blue",
    "carType": "sedan"
    "yearOfProduction": 1999,
    "price": 10.000
  },{
    "adId": "uuid"
    "carBrand": "mercedes",
    "carColor: "yellow",
    "carType": "coupe"
    "yearOfProduction": 2004,
    "price": 14.000
  },{
    "adId": "uuid"
    "carBrand": "bmw",
    "carColor: "green",
    "carType": "minivan"
    "yearOfProduction": 2007,
    "price": 6.000
 }]
```

I would like that my new array look like this:

```
[{
    "adId": "uuid"
    "carBrand": "audi",
    "carColor: "blue"
},{
    "adId": "uuid"
    "carBrand": "audi",
    "carType: "sedan"
},{
    "adId": "uuid"
    "carBrand": "audi",
    "yearOfProduction: "1999"
},{
    "adId": "uuid"
    "carBrand": "audi",
    "price: 10.000
},
{
    "adId": "uuid"
    "carBrand": "mercedes",
    "carColor: "yellow"
},{
    "adId": "uuid"
    "carBrand": "mercedes",
    "carType: "coupe"
},{
    "adId": "uuid"
    "carBrand": "mercedes",
    "yearOfProduction: "2004"
},{
    "adId": "uuid"
    "carBrand": "mercedes",
    "price: 14.000
},
    {
    "adId": "uuid"
    "carBrand": "bmw",
    "carColor: "green"
},{
    "adId": "uuid"
    "carBrand": "bmw",
    "carType": "minivan"
},{
    "adId": "uuid"
    "carBrand": "bmw",
    "yearOfProduction": 2007,
},{
    "adId": "uuid"
    "carBrand": "bmw",
    "price": 6.000
}]
```

So basically "adId" and "carBrand" properties would be present on every new object together with each one of the properties that is left. I've tried various scenarios with lodash but i simply can't make it. Any suggestions and hints are welcome, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

**One-liner**

```
arr.flatMap(({ adId, carBrand, ...rest }) => Object.entries(rest).map(([k, v]) => ({ adId, carBrand, [k]: v })))
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    adId: "uuid",
    carBrand: "audi",
    carColor: "blue",
    carType: "sedan",
    yearOfProduction: 1999,
    price: 10.0,
  },
  {
    adId: "uuid",
    carBrand: "mercedes",
    carColor: "yellow",
    carType: "coupe",
    yearOfProduction: 2004,
    price: 14.0,
  },
  {
    adId: "uuid",
    carBrand: "bmw",
    carColor: "green",
    carType: "minivan",
    yearOfProduction: 2007,
    price: 6.0,
  },
];

const result = arr.flatMap(({ adId, carBrand, ...rest }) => {
  return Object.entries(rest).map(([k, v]) => ({ adId, carBrand, [k]: v }));
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

forEach can help you out:

```
const array =  [{
    "adId": "uuid",
    "carBrand": "audi",
    "carColor": "blue",
    "carType": "sedan",
    "yearOfProduction": 1999,
    "price": 10.000
  },{
    "adId": "uuid",
    "carBrand": "mercedes",
    "carColor": "yellow",
    "carType": "coupe",
    "yearOfProduction": 2004,
    "price": 14.000
  },{
    "adId": "uuid",
    "carBrand": "bmw",
    "carColor": "green",
    "carType": "minivan",
    "yearOfProduction": 2007,
    "price": 6.000
 }]

 const newArray = []
 array.forEach(el=> {
    newArray.push({adId: el.adId, carBrand: el.carBrand, carColor: el.carColor})
    newArray.push({adId: el.adId, carBrand: el.carBrand, carType: el.carType})
    newArray.push({adId: el.adId, carBrand: el.carBrand, yearOfProduction: el.yearOfProduction})
    newArray.push({adId: el.adId, carBrand: el.carBrand, price: el.price})
 })

 console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is useful here to isolate the properties you know you want while leaving the `...rest` of the object intact for further iteration.

Here isolating `adId` and `carBrand` in the outer loop, and then iterating the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the rest of the object to construct the new objects. [Computed property assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) allows us to assign to a property from a variable (the `k` from the iterator here). Each new object is then pushed into the result array with [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```js
const arr = [{ adId: 'uuid', carBrand: 'audi', carColor: 'blue', carType: 'sedan', yearOfProduction: 1999, price: 10.0, }, { adId: 'uuid', carBrand: 'mercedes', carColor: 'yellow', carType: 'coupe', yearOfProduction: 2004, price: 14.0, }, { adId: 'uuid', carBrand: 'bmw', carColor: 'green', carType: 'minivan', yearOfProduction: 2007, price: 6.0, },];

const result = [];
for (const { adId, carBrand, ...rest } of arr) {
  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(rest)) {
    result.push({ adId, carBrand, [k]: v });
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```